# Figuring out delivery times

Tags: c#

Is there anything that can be done to improve this code? Even if its using a comepltey different technique.

This code gets a list of vanruns with rules, cutoff time and fittinging time offset. We pass in the date (either now or for future that works out the best vanrun time) We want the latest cutofftime in that day for the same warehouse. Generally is this code OK for long term use or should it be broken down more? or possibly the entire logic is flawed? Use different mechanics? Just a review if anything seriously bad is happening.

```
private ServiceData.Models.CalculatedCutOff VarnRunEngine(List<Models.VanRunPrototype.VanRun> vanRuns, DateTime matchDate)
        {
            //get the date we are interested in
            System.DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = matchDate.DayOfWeek;
            DateTime dateOfWeekLoop = new DateTime(matchDate.Ticks);

            if (vanRuns == null | (vanRuns != null && vanRuns.Count == 0))
                throw new Exception("There are no Vanruns available to work out fitting times");

            Models.VanRunPrototype.VanRun vr = null;


            int loopkill = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                loopkill += 1;

                var _vrs = vanRuns.Where(v => v.DayOfWeek == (int)dateOfWeekLoop.DayOfWeek).ToList();
                var _vrss = _vrs.Where(v => v.CutOff > dateOfWeekLoop.TimeOfDay).ToList();
                var _vrsss = _vrss.OrderBy(t => t.CutOff).ToList();


                if (_vrsss != null && _vrsss.Count > 0)
                {

                    foreach (var v in _vrsss)
                    {
                        if (v.CutOff > DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay &&
                            (vr == null || (vr.FittingFor <= v.FittingFor && (v.CutOff > vr.CutOff && v.WareHouseID == vr.WareHouseID))))
                        {
                            vr = v;
                        }
                    }

                    vr = vr ?? _vrsss.First();
                    break;
                }


                //Go to next morning
                dateOfWeekLoop = dateOfWeekLoop.Date + new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0); //For 8 in da morning? or 00:00??
                dateOfWeekLoop = dateOfWeekLoop.AddDays(1);

                if (loopkill > 14)
                    throw new Exception("Infinite loop");

            }


            DateTime co = dateOfWeekLoop.Date + vr.CutOff;

            return new TyresAndServiceData.Models.CalculatedCutOff()
            {
                CutOffTime = co,
                FittingFor = co.AddMinutes(vr.FittingIn).AddMinutes(vr.FittingInAdjust ?? 0),
                QueryDate = matchDate,
                WareHouseID = vr.WareHouseID ?? 0
            };

        }
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Code Review! Could you at least explain what the code does? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are somethings that I want to point out, that you are doing slightly wrong.

- The first one is the argument checking. Argument checking should always be the first thing you do in your code, unless it is an expensive operation or you can't do it in a straight forward manner. In your case you don't have those reasons, so move your argument checking to the beginning. You should also use `ArgumentException` when your arguments are invalid instead of `Exception`.
- The second one is that you are not following the `camelCase` convetion for your variables, you are using `_camelCase` convention which applies to instance fields. Even if you are following your own convention which is not bad, I would not recommend a `_camelCase` convention.
- You shouldn't call the method ToList from LINQ so often. Calling the method ToList transforms what may be a lazy collection to a eager collection (which occupy the memory).

Here follows the review I made to your code, I post some comments regarding some decisions I made. The code I provide may be further reviewed but I think this is a fair starting point.

```
ServiceData.Models.CalculatedCutOff VarnRunEngine(List<Models.VanRunPrototype.VanRun> vanRuns, DateTime matchDate)
{
    if (vanRuns == null || vanRuns.Count == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("There are no Vanruns available to work out fitting times", vanRuns);

    System.DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = matchDate.DayOfWeek;
    DateTime dateOfWeekLoop = new DateTime(matchDate.Ticks);
    Models.VanRunPrototype.VanRun vr = null;
    int maxIterations = 14;
    for(int i = 0; i < maxIterations && vr == null; ++i)
    {
        var vrs = vanRuns.Where(v => v.DayOfWeek == (int)dateOfWeekLoop.DayOfWeek &&
                                     v.CutOff > dateOfWeekLoop.TimeOfDay)
                         .OrderBy(t => t.CutOff);

        //vrs will never be null, it may be empty though
        //But you don't really have to check count because you will be iterating it, meaning that there is no problem
        //if vrs is empty. But if you want to preserve this check for any reason you could use vrs.Any()
        //if (vrs != null && vrs.Count() > 0)
        //{
            foreach (var v in vrs)
            {
                if ((vr == null || (vr.FittingFor <= v.FittingFor && 
                                    v.CutOff > vr.CutOff && 
                                    v.WareHouseID == vr.WareHouseID)))

                {
                    vr = v;
                }
            }

            vr = vr ?? vrs.First();
        //}

        //Go to next morning
        dateOfWeekLoop = dateOfWeekLoop.Date + new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
        dateOfWeekLoop = dateOfWeekLoop.AddDays(1);
    }

    if(vr == null){
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Couldn't calculate CutOff in {0} iterations", maxIterations));
    }

    DateTime co = dateOfWeekLoop.Date + vr.CutOff;
    return new TyresAndServiceData.Models.CalculatedCutOff()
    {
        CutOffTime = co,
        FittingFor = co.AddMinutes(vr.FittingIn).AddMinutes(vr.FittingInAdjust ?? 0),
        QueryDate = matchDate,
        WareHouseID = vr.WareHouseID ?? 0
    };

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I usually follow `camelCase` but that linq I was just trying to debug each query. I am not sure how to debug Linq during a breakpoint in the running code. So I just named those variables for temporary use, using `_` prefix. Thanks for this. Definitely looks allot easier to read.

Comment: Thanks. I cleaned up my code and implemented some more logic but essentially I used your advise and the code is easier to look at. I will also implement `ArgumentException` more often too and try to call `.ToList` less often :)

Comment: Your welcome, I'm glad that it was useful.